# How do i get the list of all the thread groups in a Test Plan

Tags: jmeter

I have a a test script which has multiple thread groups and I use a setup thread group to post to a common platform that the test has started. I currently post that the script is running now i would like to also say which all thread groups are being run and their thread counts.

I know i can do this by specifying the thread group name and thread count as User Defined Variables and then whichever thread group doesn't have a count of 0 is the one i care about.

I was wondering if there was someway to loop through all thread groups and get all the information i need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess looping through the thread groups just to get the name and thread number would be expensive. There are functions in jmeter to get these values.

> Thread Name=${__BeanShell(ctx.getThreadGroup().getName())}
>
> Thread Number=${__threadNum}

First function returns the name of current running thread group.
Second one returns the the thread number of current running thread.

Comment: This gives me information about the current thread group, how do i get information about the other thread groups?

Comment: for thread number user property ${p(tnum,1} and assign to some varaible tusers pass the value while running script in non-gui mode using -Jtnum=6 (for 6 threads).Also in script you can save name of current running thread name and value of ${tuser} to a text file and after end of script execution, you'll have a file containing list of thread group names and number of threads in it.Hope this helps! i couldn't come up with any other way to get total thread count other than using user defined variables or properties.

Comment: Sorry maybe my question wasn't clear but i want to post to a form every time i run my test and i want to include the script names and their thread counts. That is why i wanted to capture the thread group names and thread counts in a single place. The approach you have suggested works if i want to report the information after the test has run.

Comment: So mean, u don't run the scripts but just traverse them in order to get the thread group name and their count..As jmx is in xml format, i think you can write a simple program in java to travese the xml file, extract the data and write it into file.

Comment: DOM XML Parser (JAXP) Is used to get xml content in java